# Regex to match files in list with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Task : I need to match all files start from `temp` and should be end with `.txt` from list. I have tried this code but its not working.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^temp(?:_[\d]{2}[\W_])*(\d{4})?(?:[\W_][\d]{2}[\W_][\d]{2})?\.txt$')

file_names = [
    'temp_2023_05_22.txt',
    'temp.txt',
    'temp_09_05_2022.txt',
    'temp_22092023.txt'
]

matched_files = [file_name for file_name in file_names if pattern.match(file_name)]
print(matched_files)
```

`Edited`
consider this case also

```
temp20230522.txt
```

Comment: are you actually trying to extract the intermediate name (for example `"2023_05_22.txt"` from `"temp_2023_05_22.txt"`) or just reduce the list by prefix and postfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your pattern and the example data:

```
^temp(?:_(?:\d{4}_\d\d_\d\d|\d\d(_?)\d\d\1\d{4}))?\.txt$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `temp` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `_` Match literally
  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

    - `\d{4}_\d\d_\d\d` Match 4 digits `_` 2 digits `_` 2 digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\d\d(_?)\d\d\1\d{4}` Match 2 digits, optional `_` in capture group 1, 2 digits, match the same char as in group 1 using a backreference and 4 digits
  - `)` Close the non capture group
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optinal
- `\.txt` Match `.txt
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYVsN1/1).

Or a much more broader match:

```
^temp(?:_\d+_?\d+_?\d+)?\.txt$
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLNQOd/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote the following simple regex which covers all cases you mentioned plus some with alphanumeric names having underscores:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("temp(_|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z])*.txt")

file_names = [
    'temp_2023_05_22.txt',
    'temp.txt',
    'temp_09_05_2022.txt',
    'temp_22092023.txt'
]

matched_files = [file_name for file_name in file_names if pattern.match(file_name)]
print(matched_files)
```

Output:

```
['temp_2023_05_22.txt', 'temp.txt', 'temp_09_05_2022.txt', 'temp_22092023.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a direct and simple comparison, this may be simpler and more obvious without a regex

```py
[name for name in file_names if name.startswith("temp") and name.endswith(".txt")]
```

needlessly exotic variants

```py
[name for name in file_names if (name[:4] + name[-4:]) == "temp.txt"]
```

```py
list(filter(lambda n: n.startswith("temp") and n.endswith(".txt"), file_names))
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression pattern you are using seems to be overly specific and may not match all the file names that start with "temp" and end with ".txt".

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^temp.*\.txt$')

file_names = [
    'temp_2023_05_22.txt',
    'temp.txt',
    'temp_09_05_2022.txt',
    'temp_22092023.txt'
]

matched_files = [file_name for file_name in file_names if pattern.match(file_name)]
print(matched_files)
```